# The Relation between structure of compound Primary key and performance of the queries in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra

I have my own application case similar to Weather recording applications represented as following:

(cityID, sensorID, StartReadingTime, EndReadingTime, AverageValue)

Each city (cityID) has many sensors(sensorID) which reading the values of temperature.

I have composite key on (cityID,SensorID,StartReadingTime).

My application have three main queries:

1- Basic selection (Key lookup)

e.g : `SELECT *  FROM weather  WHERE cityID = ?  AND sensorID=  ? AND  StartReadingTime = ? ;`

2- Range search

e.g:  `SELECT  *  FROM weather WHERE AverageValue > ? AND AverageValue < ?`

3- Aggregation with range search

e.g:  `SELECT  count(*)  FROM weather WHERE AverageValue > ? AND AverageValue < ?`

I created the table using Cassandra CQLSH with following primary key

PRIMARY KEY ((cityID, sensorID, StartReadingTime), AverageValue)

this the only combination of primary key that i found where i can run all my queries without any error.

Depend on this structure of the primary key, Cassandra will partitioning the data depend on the first element of the PRIMARY KEY where in this case is   (cityID, sensorID, StartReadingTime) and clustering the data within the partitions depend on AverageValue. Note that i added AverageValue in the primary key so i can run greater-than and less-than operators.

My problem with this structure is that: when i run Range search and Aggregation queries, the performance is very very slow compared with Mysql, that because (as I understand) that Cassandra will do full scan in all partitions to get the results depend on structure of primary key!! i also tried to create secondary indexing on  AverageValue column, but no performance found.

My question, where is my problem with this combination of the primary, partition and cluster keys ? is there any suggestions for getting benefits from secondary indexing?

The describe of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE quote.weather (
    cityid int,
    sensorid int,
    startreadingtime double,
    averagevalue double,
    endreadingtime double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((cityid, sensorid, startreadingtime), averagevalue)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (averagevalue ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX av_index ON quote.weather (averagevalue);
```

Comment: In order to understand your complete schema, could you run a `DESCRIBE TABLE <table_name>` on that table?

Comment: I added the description of the table

Comment: Offhand, it looks like your schema would be ideal for the queries. The only thing non-ideal about it is that the range queries touches all nodes because its not targeted to specific partitions. The other thing to note is that secondary indexes generally do the same so I would frown up using them as well. If you're doing a lot of reads in comparison to writes, I would suggest trying the `LeveledCompactionStrategy`. It generally limits the amount of SSTables to be read from but still doesn't limit the number of nodes to read from with the range queries. Sorry that I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: thank you for your reply 'Will C', as i understand, Cassandra will not perform better than Mysql for my application scenario. and this what i found so far. I tried different combination of primary key order such as (cityID, averageValue, sensorID, startReadingTime ) to be clustered by averageValue, and i got worst results.

Comment: Generally, Cassandra may not perform as well as MySQL for reads. It solves the problem where MySQL is generally worse off, high writes. If I understood what you said, the `(cityID, averageValue, sensorID, startReadingTime)` is your new composite key? In that scenario it might be worse because its touching all the nodes that are in a given range in addition to heavy I/O on trying to read because `averageValue` is not sorted on disk the way you'd like to access it. I suspect you might be able to get better results for that composite key if you add the `cityID` to your range query though.